# What is the difference between Application.Current.Resources and Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I have global `ResourceDictionary` defined in my `App.xaml` file.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="yolo" TargetType="Grid" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I've had set breakpoint in random `Page` and checked difference in debugger:

```
Application.Current.Resources = 1
Resources = 0
```

What's the `this.Resources`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Application.Current.Resources`**

Contains the resources that are declared in the `App.xaml` file, which can be seen the entire application.

**`this.Resources`**

Contains the resources that are defined locally for any control, such as `Window`, `UserControl` and are only available within this control.

Example with `Window`:

`XAML`

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

<Window.Resources>
    <sys:String x:Key="MyString">TestString</sys:String>
</Window.Resources>
```

`Code-behind`

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string test = this.Resources["MyString"] as string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> What's the `this.Resources`?

It's the resource dictionary of the control whose code-behind code we are writing in.

On the other hand `Application.Current.Resources` is the resource dictionary of the application object itself.

If you are writing code inside `App.xaml.cs`, then `Resources` and `Application.Current.Resources` will refer to the same object.